# how to refund only Partial amount while creating memo

Tags: magento2, orders, refund

I have a site where I have to refund Partial amount of the order to the customer.

The product price is 1000 and it's weight is 100 grams, after manufacturing the weight of the product is not exactly the same.

So after complete the order I have to return some amount to the customer based on the final weight of the final product. how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you will have to set it in `adjustment fee` section while doing Credit Memo.

Whatever is paid, you can enter that amount in `adjustment fee` section and then it will refund the remaining one.

**Example**

If total is $100 and customer has paid $40, then put $60 in adjustment fee section then system will refund $40.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below instruction.

**All order**

[image]

If you need refund four product change Qty 1 to 0 in **Qty to Refund** tab.

[image]

Hope this will helps to you.

Comment: What Magento Version are you using? My Qty fields are missing.

Comment: clearly magento 2 based on the GUI pic

Answer (score 0):

This does NOT work.
If "qty to be refunded" is 1, then the entire item will not be included anymore in a shipment created after the refund.