# Magento 2.2.0 partial Credit Memo/Refund doesn't work properly

Tags: magento2, creditmemo, refund, magento2.2

We have to try partial credit memo for Magento 2.2.0 shop admin for below step:

1) Proceed order with default payment and Grand Total are `€37.00`

2) Create the Invoice.

3) Try to Credit memo with Adjustment Fee are `€10.00`

After refund, Order status set **Closed** status.

> Order History:

[image]

> Order Total:

[image]

And **Credit memo** button are not available in order history.

[image]

How to fix this issue....!

Comment: Did find any work around. I am facing this issue when I can't refund any further as one refund was created for refund shipping now the custumer returned the item and need to refund but can't there is no credit memo button?

Comment: @JulianoVargas, No. We does not resolve this issue. In this issue exist  in latest Magento CE_2.2.5. We have rise this issue in Magento github, but Magento team asked does not face this issue. Refer this https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10636

Answer (score 0):

It's the normal behavior, as you set the adjustment fee when creating the credit memo. Since basically the adjustment fee will decrease the amount of credit memo. You didn't tell about it in the Github issue report, btw.

Look at this thread https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/83818/66719 for more explanation